# How to Attach styleSheet.css in tomcat (Servlet)

Tags: servlets, tomcat6, netbeans6.7

I have made a webpage in Servlet and now i want to add a stylesheet.css to it 
Where should i exactly put the .css file ? like in ROOT of tomcat or some where else and what exact path i have to use??

**link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'**

Thanks
Sundhas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks EveryOne!
I figured this out

Well actually you don't have to paste the FILE.CSS in Root of tomcat
you actually have to paste the .css file where your netbeans Projects reside
for example **C://Documents and settings/NetbeansProject/ProjectName/Web
Paste the .Css over there**

and so this remains same : link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'

~Sundhas~

Answer (score 1):

Put the file somewhere in WebContent. There where your JSP files also are. Or did you abuse the Servlet to generate the HTML output? Well, at least, the public files needs to be placed in the WebContent folder. The folder name might differ from environment to environment, but it is at least the very same root folder where the `WEB-INF` folder resides. You normally place public content there.

Answer (score 1):

Put your css into the `webcontent` folder. In the `href` provide an absolute link to the css and for html formatting use `out.prinln` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a relative path, it should be in the same location as your jsp. If you write your HTML in the Servlet, it should be placed in the root of the webapp.

Comment: yes that .css resides in Root folder but still its not wroking :S

do i need to change somehthing in this path? i mean while attaching style sheet
link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'

like some path in href= "" ???